# asp.net mvc 4 intranet application users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im in the process of building a intranet application using windows authentication. The problem im having is that if 2 users use the application at the same time, for some reason the user that last opened the page's details are on both sessions. Im not using a database.

Is there a way to give each user an instance of the application?

Comment: I have 2 users log in then after the second logged in both users welcome message is the same. 

What I have in my app is a user model that gets populated from active directory. When the second user logs in the first user sees the second users data.

Something is very wrong. Im rather new to this so it can be a error on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have stored the model in a static property somewhere which might explain the behavior. You mentioned that you are not using a database, so I guess you have *invented* some persistence in your application.

If you don't to persist user specific data you could use Session instead of static properties.

Comment: The user model is static, the problem i have with making it a nonstatic class is that i need to pass info to the _layout file.

Comment: Well that explains the problems you are having. You should not use static fields. Store it in the `Session`. Your Layout could retrieve it from there.